# Swapping elements with event handlers

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have following structure

```
<div id="mainblock">

   <div id="inner1">
     some content in inner1
   </div>
   <div id="innersub1">
     <input type="submit" id="go" value="go">
     <input type="submit" id="delete" value="delete">
   </div>

    <div id="inner2">
     some content in inner2
   </div>
   <div id="innersub2">
     <input type="submit" id="go" value="go">
     <input type="submit" id="delete" value="delete">
    </div>
```

I need to exchange content between inner1 and inner2 div inluding ids. So, the id's change like  inner1 becomes inner2,innersub1 becomes innersub2, and viceversa. I have been able to do this, using jquery. Now, go and delete buttons have attached handlers. But, now when I click "edit", it shows previous content before exchange. So, how should I reattach these handlers? Can I handle this swapping of content with handlers in some other way?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can manually (in code) [detach](http://api.jquery.com/unbind/) reattach them. Alternately you can just hide an unhide the buttons you need and leave the event handlers as they are.